# Can I somehow modify the math autocorrect list in excel by using vba code?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to access the math autocorrect list of Excel 2016, but I can't find an object with methods to do so.

The reason is that I'm typing a lot of math stuff in Excel.
That's why I'd like to print all the math autocorrect entries in a list as a first step.
Then modify this list for my needs, that is deleting a lot of the entries, because there are too much.
Then write this list back in the math autocorrect list of Excel.

I can access the standard autocorrect list by using application.autocorrect.
 But for the math autocorrect list I can't find an object.
In Word it's application.omathautocorrect, but that doesn't work in Excel.

Comment: I don't know of a way of doing this (doesn't mean it does not exist) but I am thinking custom functions may help you. Do you do a lot of repetitive math? Writing a custom function could speed up your work flow

Comment: [Would this be helpfull?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2013_release/how-to-use-math-autocorrect-in-excel/dadf030c-2ba3-4080-9383-3050705792cf).

Comment: @JvdV Thanks a lot, that sounds good. I'll work through it.